# How to create a ListView In Fragment for Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, listview, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I want to create a `ListView` in Fragment using Xamarin Android.

1. Code as follows (`Framgent2.cs`):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using  Android.Support.V4.App;

namespace NavigationDrawerTest
{
    public class Fragment2 : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
    {
        private List<string> mItems;
        private ListView mListView;

        public override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
            //SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Fragment2_Layout);
            mListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.myListView);

            mItems = new List<string> ();
            mItems.Add ("One");
            mItems.Add ("Two");
            mItems.Add ("Three");
            mItems.Add ("Four");
            mItems.Add ("Five");

            ArrayAdapter <string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string> (this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, mItems);
            mListView.Adapter = adapter;
        }

        public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Fragment2_Layout, container, false);
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Error in this code as follows

[image: Fragment2.cs error image]

2. Code as follow Fragment2_layout.axml

[image: Fragment2_layout.axml code as image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Fragment2_Layout, container, false);
        mListView = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.myListView);

        mItems = new List<string> ();
        mItems.Add ("One");
        mItems.Add ("Two");
        mItems.Add ("Three");
        mItems.Add ("Four");
        mItems.Add ("Five");

        ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(Context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, objects: mItems.ToArray());

        mListView.Adapter = adapter;

        return view;
    }
```

if your only purpose is to manage a ListView then checkout [ListFragment](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/part_3_-_specialized_fragment_classes/)

Comment: Thanks for solution ,just worked fine. I want to ask another question . How to create ListView Click Listener in it . If you would possible to give an example or a link to an example , it would be great. @wishmaster